# Validation an entity class contains subclass in spring MVC

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-validator

please help me.
I'm working validate form. The fields of class student as "name","address","email" display message when i click submit form but my problem is the fields that class student contains relationship as class major is not display message. I tried to put @Valid annotations and i get the same a result.

I get an errors: Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type com.springmvc.entities.Major for property major; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type java.lang.String to required type com.springmvc.entities.Major for property major: no matching editors or conversion strategy found.

Can someone help me or give me solutions ? I'm so grateful !

I sincerely apologize if my English is not good

```
@Entity(name="student")
public class Student{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  int id;

  @NotNull(message="Your name must not null !")
  String name;

  @NotNull(message="Your address must not null !")
  String address;

  @NotNull(message="Your email must not null !")
  String email;

  @NotNull(message="Select a major !")
  @Valid
  @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name="idMajor")
  private Major major;

  //getter - setter ...
}



@Entity(name="major")
public Class Major{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  int idMajor;
  String major;

  //getter - setter ...
}


//My controller

@Controller
public class StudentController{

  @Autowired
  StudentService studentService;

  @InitBinder
  public void InitBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
     StringTrimmerEditor stringTrimmerEditor = new StringTrimmerEditor(true);
     binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, stringTrimmerEditor);
  }



    @ModelAttribute("studentForm")
      public Student studentForm()
        {
           return new Student();
        }

  @RequestMapping(value="/saveStudent",method= RequestMethod.POST)
  public String SaveStudent(@Valid @ModelAttribute("studentForm") Student 
  student,BindingResult bindingResult, ModelMap model) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
    {
        return "page-student";
    }
    else {
        model.addAttribute("msg", "Save success!");
                studentService.SaveStudent(student);
        return "page-student;
    }
   }

}


//My View (page-student.jsp) 

 <form:form action="saveStudent" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" 
 modelAttribute="studentForm" >

    <p>Name:<form:input path="name"/></p>
    <form:errors path="name" cssClass="error" /> // Validate ok !

    <p>Address:<form:input path="address"/></p>
    <form:errors path="address" cssClass="error" /> // Validate ok !

    <p>Email:<form:input path="email"/></p>
    <form:errors path="email" cssClass="error" /> // Validate ok !

    <p>Major:<form:select  path="major">                                     
    <form:option value="0">-- Select --</form:option>

      <c:forEach var="major" items="${major}">
         <form:option value="${major.getIdMajor()}">
             ${major.getMajor()} 
          </form:option>                                     
       </c:forEach>

    </form:select></p>
   <form:errors path="major" cssClass="error" />
  // I get an errors as I  mentioned in my description above.

    <form:button type="submit" >Submit</form:button>
</form:form>
```

Comment: You need to register a Spring converter that will convert the string string id og the selected major to the entity: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54712884/1356423

Comment: If using Spring Data repositories, the `DomainClassConverter` is available to do this automatically.

Comment: Does `DomainClassConverter` handle nested properties? Documentation only refers to domain types in method signatures. Good to know if it does.

Comment: @AlanHay thanks for support me. Could you suggest for me another sample ?

Comment: @chrylis thanks for support me. Could you tell me how to use it ?

Comment: @AlanHay Maybe i displayed message fine, but when I don't select or select, I still get the same message